# Combining ASP.NET Controller Route with AngularJS object id

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I have an ASP.NET View using server-side @foreaches, now replaced with AngularJS.

Now I use `ng-repeat="record in records"`, and I don't use anymore the `@foreach`.

The actual code that worked with `@record.Id` now does not work with `{{record.id}}`:

```
<td class="text-nowrap">
    <a asp-controller="Records" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="{{record.id}}">Edit</a>
    <a asp-controller="Records" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="{{record.id}}">View</a>
    <a asp-controller="Records" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="{{record.id}}">Delete</a>
</td>
```

obviously, because the `@record.Id` was on the server side...

Now, the solution I see it to set something like

```
<a href="/Records/Edit/{{record.id}}"></a>
```

However if the controller's route will change it could lead to nowhere... Is there a way to workaround that?

PS.

Some more code for better understanding:

```
<div ng-app="tablesApp" ng-controller="tablesController as tc">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in records">
      <td>{{record.name}}</td>
      <td>{{record.description}}</td>
      <td>
        <a asp-controller="Records" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="{{record.id}}">Edit</a>
        <a asp-controller="Records" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="{{record.id}}">View</a>
        <a asp-controller="Records" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="{{record.id}}">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

JS Controller:

```
$http.get("/api/Records")
    .then(function (response) {
        tc.records = response.data;
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you use `foreach` in razor view (obviously you do) then you can't use angular syntax `{{record.id}}` you have to use `@record.id`

But if you get records, as an array/list whatever, in AngularJs then you have to change your html and use `ng-repeat`

-- Edit

Sorry just see your code again, you used `asp-action` and `asp-controller` etc
They are TAG HELPERS from core version, in other words they will get rendered on the server side and what you will get in the browser actually is anchor link like

`<a href="/Records/Edit/{{record.id}}" >Edit</a>`

AngularJs as you know is client side so it won't render. Either use `@Url.Action` as you already did or you could remove `asp-route-id` and add the id later using custom directive.

Comment: I use already `ng-repeat="record in records"`, and I don't use anymore the `@foreach`

Comment: Then could you please post the wrapper element that contains `ng-repeat`? It would be better if you post the one that contains `ng-controller`

Comment: Let's suppose the `ng-repeat="record in records"` is located in the `<td>` tag from the code above. How does it change the solution?

Comment: A lot of scenarios, I asked for `ng-controller` to check if you have overlap which isn't allowed in AngularJs. Maybe you use angular routing, maybe you don't get any result at all from your controller etc ..
Anyway good luck :)

Comment: Thanks. I added the code you asked... I don't know the angular routing, could it help in that case?

Comment: thanks. however is the same information that in the OP, I mean, any new elements...

Answer (score 1):

Actually a little bit better option that the hardcoded route is to use

```
<a href="@Url.Action(action: "Edit", controller: "Records")/{{record.id}}" ></a>
```

However this one is supposed to have the `{ActionRoute}/{id}` fixed structure...